# java null pointer exception on calling sending Function From two differerent classes of objects

Tags: java

```
DatagramPacket sendingPackets;
byte[] hellodata;
public void sendData(String toServer, String ip, int port)
{

    try
    {
        DatagramSocket sendingSocket=new DatagramSocket();
        System.out.println("From manipulate ip="+ip+"and port ="+port+toServer);

       hellodata = toServer.getBytes();
        sendingPackets = new DatagramPacket(hellodata, hellodata.length,     InetAddress.getByName(ip), port);
        sendingSocket.send(sendingPackets);
        // sendingSocket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sending Error :" + EX, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}


public void sendmyData(String d, String ip,int port)
{
    sr = new SendAndRecieveZone();
    sr.sendData(d, ip, port);
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
{                                             
    srs = new SendAndRecieveZone();
    data = jTextField1.getText();
    srs.sendData(d, ip, port);   
}
```

sendData() this function is in "SendAndRecieveZone" class. sendmyData() is the function of one separate class "loginClass". jButton1ActionPerformed() is in one another class "mainClass". I tried to call the sendData() from loginClass and mainClass but the first call from "loginClass" is success but when i try to call from "mainClass" it creates null pointer exception. i debuged it and found err at line "srs.sendData(d, ip, port);" of mainClass. Dont Know where it gone wrong. Also when loginClass calls multiple times the sendData() function it doesnot create any err.

Comment: You can put a break point in the debugger and see exactly which object is causing the null pointer exception.

Comment: What do you mean "the function object calling to the sending function"? Could you provide the code which calls the function?

Comment: It's pretty hard to detect the reason for your NullPointerException from what you've posted. You might want to update your question with more pointers, including your exception stack trace.

Comment: Does there any chances to cause the err cause of using same socket buy two different objects? I tried using different object it wont work but when i try to send using only single object it works. is it possible?

Comment: Without posting a stack trace and telling us where the exception is thrown, it's going to be impossible for anybody to help you.  Please edit your post and add the stack trace.

Comment: Error is obviously thrown form the code Line SendingSocket.send() while it is called 2nd time from second class. Its fine with first call from the first class.

Comment: Provide more information, edit your question with clear language and stack trace